# Cypress : Run all test fail only in interactive mode and failed test only concern api Testing

Tags: typescript, cypress, keycloak, e2e-testing

We use cypress for end to end and api call testing, and it goes well. But We are facing a weird issue when we try to run all specs in interactive mode :

Failed tests concern all tests that call our api with the keyclaok token in localstorage. The reason is the token is null while it is not in localstorage.

running the concerned specs one by one works fine, and keycloak token is gotten and sent.

We tried to extends tokenExperation and check refresh link. Unfortunately, that was not the problem. All goes fine

I have read there were an old issues that concern run all in interactive mode.

Thank you and we hope to get some suggest from you

Comment: Can you post the issue that you found concerning interactive mode?

Comment: Is there a reason you are running all specs in interactive mode instead of headless? Interactive mode basically appends all the tests together as if it were one giant test file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.